# Get stuck in posting to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in facebook apps development and I'm get stuck on how to post to facebook.
I've read tutorials, and do according to them.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));


//Request params
if(!($_GET['code'])) {
    header("Location:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=" . urlencode("http://localhost/facebook/examples/") . "&scope=publish_stream");
    //header("Location:http://www.google.com");
     exit;
} 

$token = $_GET['code'];
echo "token " . $token


$status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'This post came from my app.', 'access_token' => $token));
var_dump($status);

?>
```

Result:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Bad signature thrown in     C:\wamp\www\facebook\examples\facebook.php on line 543

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are using raw OAuth login and at the same time using facebook php SDK.
Don't do it like that, if you are using SDK us it all the way:

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));

if (!$facebook->getSession()) 
{
    header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'publish_stream')));
}
else
{
    $status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'This post came from my app.'));
    var_dump($status);
}

?>
```

SDK will handle token him self ;)